# Where is a good Visual Studio Macro to iterate and list all menus (VS2008 if pos.)?

Tags: visual-studio, menu, visual-studio-macros

I've been explained there is a Macro which iterates through all the menus. Having checked CodeProject, and various places on the web I'm out of luck so far.

Does anyone know any better?

Thanks
Beth

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a list of all available commands, you can take a look at the "Keyboard" page in Tools->Options.